# hide div when clicking outside the container with jquery

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide

I want to hide a div when they click out of it. For that I have this code that works perfectly:

```
var box3=$(".despcnt");
box3.mouseup(function () {
    return false;
});

$(this).mouseup(function (a) {
    if(!($(a.target).parent(".despcnt").length>0)){
        box3.removeClass("dino");box3.hide()
    }
});
```

But I want to exclude from the class. Despcnt a link that has the class desplcnt so when clicking outside the den or closes that same link ... not tried putting it did not work.

Any idea?

HTML

```
<a class="desplcnt" href="#">Link</a>
<div class="despcnt">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-value="1" href="#">Title</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please clarify what's the problem - it's really hard to understand what you're trying to say

Comment: What does that second paragraph mean?

Comment: The code works fine, when they click outside the div is closed. But if you click on the link. Desplcnt not closed and that's what I want.

Sorry if you do not understand, I use google translate

Comment: @jon90, does this help? [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxu4W/)

Comment: Yeah, right ... but I do not work. Could it be because I have despcnt hidden div? and open it with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $despcnt = $(".despcnt");
```

```
/* Hide the popup whereas clicking outside */
$(document).on("click", function() {
  $despcnt.hide();
});
```

```
/* Don't hide the popup whereas clicking inside */
$despcnt.on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, when you click on title, you want link to hide. But when you click anywhere else, you want title to hide? If so, you can assign `Title` a `mouseup` event, and then hide the link from there, then use `e.stopPropagation()` in order to bypass the global `mouseup` attached to window when you used `this`. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pUnvR/1/

Here is the code:

html

```
<a class="desplcnt" href="#">Link</a>
<div class="despcnt">
 <ul>
    <li><a data-value="1" href="#">Title</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
var box3=$(".despcnt");
box3.mouseup(function (e) {
    $(".desplcnt").hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(this).mouseup(function (a) {
    if(!($(a.target).parent(".despcnt").length>0)){
        box3.removeClass("dino");
        box3.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: By clicking on .desplcnt or outside the container is hidden. But I will not, look http://jsfiddle.net/zxu4W/2/